# Using Coroutines inside splashscreen

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-jetpack-compose, coroutine

Hi i have made my own splashscreen in jetpack compose and i want to be able to use coroutines.launch within this screen. Though when i try to do this i get an error and it tells me to import so i click import and it does but still there is an error. I have no clue why. Is it okey to use coroutines inside splashscreen? Here is my code...

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


@Composable
fun SplashScreen(navController: NavController, viewModel : SplashViewModel = hiltViewModel()){
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        val overshootInterpolator = remember {
            OvershootInterpolator(2f)
        }

        val scale = remember {
            Animatable(0f)
        }
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
            scale.animateTo(
                targetValue = 1f,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 500,
                    easing = {
                        overshootInterpolator.getInterpolation(it)
                    }
                )
            )
            delay(Constants.SPLASH_SCREEN_DURATION)
            navController.popBackStack()
            viewModel.checkIfUserExists()
            CoroutineScope.launch {

                viewModel.event.collect{event ->
                    when(event){
                        is AuthEvent.Success -> navController.navigate(PaperSellerScreens.CustomerListScreen.name)
                        is AuthEvent.Failure -> navController.navigate(PaperSellerScreens.LoginScreen.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val painterIcon = painterResource(R.drawable.logo_size_invert)
        val painterBackground = painterResource(id = R.drawable.paper_seller_background)
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
            Image(painter = painterBackground, contentDescription = "SplashScreen",contentScale = ContentScale.Crop, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
            Image(painterIcon, "Icon Image", modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp, 200.dp)
                .scale(scale.value)
                .align(
                    Alignment.Center
                )
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)))
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. You have a typo, it should be `coroutineScope` instead if `CoroutineScope`
2. You don't need `coroutineScope.launch` in the first place, as `LaunchedEffect` is already run on a coroutine scope, so you can call suspend functions - as you've already used `scale.animateTo` and `delay`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collectAsState` without `CoroutineScope.launch`

```
val event by viewModel.event.collectAsState(initial = AuthEvent.Checking)
when(event){
   is AuthEvent.Success ->  ...
   is AuthEvent.Failure ->  ...
   is AuthEvent.Checking -> // do nothing
}
```